# Angular route children with parent custom matcher

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular15

I'm trying to use a regex on the parent route and then also have child routes, so I tried this:

```js
const barcodeRoute = () => (segments: UrlSegment[]) => {
    if (!segments.length)
        return null

    const segment = segments[0]
    return barcodeRegex.test(segment.path) ? {consumed: [segment], posParams: {barcode: segment}} : null
}

export const routes: Routes = [
    {
        component: DisplayRootComponent,
        matcher: barcodeRoute(),
        children: [
            {
                path: 'safety-assessment',
                loadComponent: () => import('./app/safety-assessment/safety-assessment/safety-assessment.component')
                    .then(x => x.SafetyAssessmentComponent)
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

The regex will match and display the `DisplayRootComponent`, but if I append `/safety-assessment` to the end of the route, it still goes to the `DisplayRootComponent` instead of `SafetyAssessmentComponent`.

All the other posts I've seen on this are solved by "consuming" part of the url segments, which I've done, so I'm not sure what I'm missing.

A very simplified example without matchers or lazy loading can be see at [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-yjbpdy?file=src%2Fmain.ts).

Comment: did you try pathMatch?

Comment: @yo_sup Can you be more specific please?  I tried putting `pathMatch: full` in the parent component but that didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a stackblitz with your code and it works as expected.

Go to https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-nested-routing-6xezhp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp-routing.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fhome%2Fhome.component.html

then click the link at the bottom. If it's still not working for you, perhaps you need to look at your barcode regex.

**Update** Based on your StackBlitz, I can see that you are not including `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in your parent anywhere. That's why the child is not showing. When you have nested routes, the child doesn't *replace* the parent, it is shown *in addition to* the parent. If you want it to replace the parent, then the route should be a sibling of the parent, not a child of the parent.

Here is an updated version of your StackBlitz showing the child.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-jyc1mv?file=src%2Fparent.component.ts,src%2Fmain.ts

Comment: I greatly simplified the example, and put a stackblitz showing the problem at https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-yjbpdy?file=src%2Fmain.ts